# Problems migrating GoDaddy record sets to AWS Route 53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, mx-record, cname-record, amazon-route53

I've migrated a domain name from GoDaddy to AWS's Route 53. The problem I'm having is that emails are not being delivered to the email exchange. Everything else seems to be working just fine.

I've contacted GoDaddy about this, and they said I need to copy over the record sets from my domain on GoDaddy to Route 53. Below is a picture of my GoDaddy record sets.

[Picture of GoDaddy record sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9tzX.png)

After I got these, I then went to my Route 53 app and included these record sets.

[Picture of AWS record sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcvwa.png)

Unfortunately, Route 53 wouldn't allow me to add the CNAMEs to the record sets because their's a conflict with the SOA record.

RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name harborflowers.com. is not permitted at apex in zone harborflowers.com.

So I just ignored it to see if it would still work, but currently, I'm still unable to receive emails from my domain and I'm getting send failures when trying to email my address at that domain.

My question is, how can I have Route 53 redirect emails to my GoDaddy email client?

Comment: Screenshot of R53 zone content would be nice too

Comment: *"Unfortunately, Route 53 wouldn't allow me to add the CNAMEs to the record sets because their's a conflict with the SOA record."*  There is no CNAME shown at the apex in the screen shot so *something* about what you're doing isn't the same as what you should be doing.

Comment: @Putnik I just added a picture of the AWS record sets.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot There are CNAMEs clearly in the GoDaddy record sets.

Comment: @grantathon none of them are at the apex of the zone.  They all have associated hostnames and none of them would have triggered the error about conflicting with the SOA.

Answer (score 0):

First,

> redirect emails to my GoDaddy email client

does not make any sense in terms of DNS. The DNS service should have a record which points at the server which is designated to process all incoming mail for your domain.

Second, to configure which server should process incoming email for the domain, the domain zone *(with small exception)* should have `MX` record. Make sure you've configured it at R53.

**UPDATE:**
the mail processed server is at outlook, but you want to read mail via godaddy (gd). This is the most confusing point and this is why you haven't received the answer so far. You're confused by/with two separate and totally independent parts: MX server (mail processor) and your mail client.

From what I see, your MX record id correct if you want to have processing at outlook. To read mail at gd you should configure the gd client to use outlook's pop3/imap servers (and perhaps smtp too). Alternatively you can use gd mx (if they provide any), I assume gd mail client uses gd mail processor by default.

Comment: I added a picture of the AWS record sets to the question, which includes the MX record. Pardon my ignorance on the topic, this is all fairly new to me.

Comment: @grantathon I see you have MX record which points at `harborflowers-com.mail.protection.outlook.com`. If this is not your mail exchanger then replace this value with correct one (double-check typos!). If this is correct then contact outlook.com support. MX is the only record which is responsible for mail delivery, unless micro$oft invented something really new.

Comment: I think I got it, have just updated the answer.